# Change pentaho dashboards jquery version

Tags: jquery, pentaho

I have biserver-ce version 6.0.1.0, and it comes with jquery 1.9.1.

I want to update it to jquery version 3.2.1 (latest), but pentaho doesn't simply add the file, it generates it somehow.

All I could find it was that it keeps the file in this directory:

\pentaho-solutions\system\common-ui\resources\web\jquery-1.9.1.js

Tried to replace it with the new version, didn't work.

Then I searched for every jquery file in the server folder:

```
\pentaho-solutions\system\pentaho-cdf\js\compressed\lib
\pentaho-solutions\system\pentaho-cdf\js\lib
\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\mantle\browser\lib
\pentaho-solutions\system\saiku\ui\js
\pentaho-solutions\system\common-ui\resources\web
\pentaho-solutions\system\pentaho-cdf\js-legacy\lib
```

Replace them all, but $.fn.jQuery still says "1.9.1".

Answer (score 0):

You require to rebuild biserver-ce (and projects it depends on) with corrected dependencies. Because pentaho modified and rebuild depended js on build time.